# Parsing JSON in node express - ends up with \n between delimiters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing, stringify

I'm sending an Ajax request to an express endpoint, like so:

```
var postData = {
      method: "POST",
      url: "/order/address",
      data: { order: JSON.stringify(addressFields) },
      cache: false
    };

    updateAjax = $.ajax(postData).done(function(data) {
```

The address object being sent is a JSON array. I have confirmed it is not already stringified prior to doing this in the post data object.

It posts to a server running node express, with a path of /order/address.

The express route is as follows, only showing up to the point the json gets parsed, as it's the only relevant parts of this:

```
router.route('/')
  .post(function (req, res, next) {
    // prevents caching of customer information
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');

    const addresses = JSON.parse(req.body.order);
```

Prior to being parsed, req.body.order is :

`[{\"isDefaultShipping\":true,\"firstName\":\"\",\"lastName\":\"\",\"street1\":\"\",\"street2\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"postcode\":\"\",\"region\":\"\",\"country\":\"GB\",\"phone\":\"\",\"isDefaultBilling\":true}]`

And, here is the problem I'm having, after parsing it ends up as an invalid JSON object:

`[\n  {\n    isDefaultShipping: true,\n    firstName: '',\n    lastName: '',\n    street1: '',\n    street2: '',\n    city: '',\n    postcode: '',\n    region: '',\n    country: 'GB',\n    phone: '',\n    isDefaultBilling: true\n  }\n]`

I have been unable to remove the line breaks - and I guess there's line breaks that are not visible, within the stringified data that is being parsed - but I can't for the life of me remove them?

EDIT: Someone has kindly pointed out my stupidity (politely), that the output above, with the \n linebreaks, is my logger, so ignore that part.
Leaving it in there - well, because it would be rude to remove this part of my question that I got an answer on.

Postman shows the following issue as it hits the JSON.parse line in the route:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0\n    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: but why are you stringifying your data in the first place? And then re-parsing it on the other end? Isn't it a waste of resources? Also it creates your problem

Comment: Were are you seeing that output, yes it's invalid JSON, but it's a valid Javascript array.

Comment: "an invalid JSON object" — Is it still a string then? Or is it an array? Are there really line breaks or are they just how your debugging tool is showing you the object?

Comment: i am able to parse it successfuly using `JSON.parse("[{\"isDefaultShipping\":true,\"firstName\":\"\",\"lastName\":\"\",\"street1\":\"\",\"street2\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"postcode\":\"\",\"region\":\"\",\"country\":\"GB\",\"phone\":\"\",\"isDefaultBilling\":true}]");`

Comment: Actually, I think this is my debugging tool showing the output as having line breaks.

Comment: Using postman, it errors at the JSON.parse line with the classic: ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0\n    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)```

Comment: @MatthewTrow — So `req.body.order` is undefined … which means something is wrong with how you are constructing the request in Postman. The JS you have to make the request appears to be fine.

Comment: Yeah - that's possible. This all boils down to an error in the browser console, ```XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost:3007/order/address
Line Number 1, Column 1:```

But this may well be triggers AFTER node express has done it's work and the ajax request has been completed, but it doesn't look like it to me - it's erroring in the router.

Comment: Ok, so actually setting the content-type correctly in the route has resolved the browser error. I think I've gone down a rabbit hole trying to solve something, by looking at the wrong error :( - thanks for the comments though everyone! - good bit of rubber ducking.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace \n

```
router.route('/')
  .post(function (req, res, next) {
    // prevents caching of customer information
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');

    const addresses = JSON.parse(req.body.order).replace(\[\n]+\, '');
```

Comment: It's not a string after it has been parsed, it's an object.